# Examples of certain contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $T:M\to M$ satisfying $d(T(x),T(y))\le (1/2)d(x,y)$ but $T$ has no fixed points. Can you give an example of such and metric space and a mapping $T$ ?

Comment: Given your rapid fire contraction mapping questions, it seems you are learning the Banach fixed point theorem. To put yourself in a position to answer this yourself in a position to answer this question yourself, what is missing from the hypotheses here that would insure the existence of a fixed point? What do the $M$'s given in the answers below have in common?

Comment: oh, and please put more effort into your posts. You just posted a question that looks like it came directly from a homework, providing none of your own thoughts.

Comment: I apologize if I seem to ask questions without putting my own effort. I have genuinely thought about these problems before posting them on this website. But given my lack of knowledge(and talent as well), I was not able to solve these problems. My motive is to learn only.

Comment: I was not able to produce an example. I'm not sure if I can write in words, the thought process behind this. I apologize again if my motive seems to solve some "homework" problems.

Comment: Lack of talent is no excuse.

Comment: See, I can't even provide proper reasons for my inability.

Comment: @JohnMitchell then show us some of your attempts, explain some of your thoughts. I second copper.hat, at this level, talent is not what is stopping anyone

Comment: Since you seem to be having difficulty asking Questions of this kind (they appear to be copied from a written source) as well as difficulty in digesting the Answers thoughtfully provided below, my suggestion is to drop back and work on exercises and material which is of a more preliminary nature.  For example, this Question makes no mention of a completeness property of a metric space, but that is a topic which is essential to understanding existence of fixed points of contraction mappings.  I suspect you've jumped over some other important preliminaries that affect problem solving tactics.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $M=(0,1)$ with the usual metric and $T(x)=x/3$.
Can you see what happens?

Comment: that was literally the example i was typing. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be the space of real sequences that are zero after some finite index.

Let $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|_\infty$, and $f(x) = (1,{x_1\over 2}, {x_2\over 2},...)$.

Note that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|_\infty = {1 \over 2} \|x-y\|_\infty$.

However, $f$ has no fixed points.

Answer (score 1):

$M:=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}; d(x,y)=|x-y|.$

Set $T:M \to M$ to be $T(x)=x/2.$

It satisfies the request because $d(T(x),T(y))=|x/2-y/2|=1/2 \cdot|x-y|=1/2 \cdot d(x,y).$